# Вывод данных для определенного пользователя (rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Есть цель - дать возможность пользователю переключаться между events, которые он создал, и events, которые создали все пользователи нажатием кнопки.

Я знаю как выводить из базы данных один из вариантов, а вот как сделать это из пользовательского интерфейса - нет. Подскажите пожалуйста, как это сделать? Желательно не подключая дополнительные гемы

Метод index в контроллере:

```
def index
    @events = Event.all #вывод всей таблицы
    @events = Event.where(author_id: current_user.id) #вывод авторских events
end
```

Заранее спасибо за ответ)

Answer (score 1):

Во первых у вас в контроллере 2 переменные `@events`, если делать так, то имена должны быть, естественно, разные. В вашем случае имеет смысл оставить только `@events = Event.all`, так как передавать во 'view' 2 массива, один из которых содержит другой - нецелесообразно. Для того чтобы вывести записи только для конкретного юзера во `view` пишите

 @events.where(author_id: current_user).each do |event| 
    #code with event... 
 end 
 (не забывая про `<℅ ... ℅>`)
  а отображение либо всех записей либо автора можно сделать через вывод в 2 таблицы и отображение/скрытие их с помощью js.